# Selenium: Clicking on img button open the url in new tab but not returning the url in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an **img** for the linked in link as below

```
<span class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body1 css-lkp0s4">
<img alt="linkedin icon" srcset="https://d3ml3b6vywsj0z.cloudfront.net/website/v2/icons_v2/linkedin_icon_blue_fill.svg 1x, https://d3ml3b6vywsj0z.cloudfront.net/website/v2/icons_v2/linkedin_icon_blue_fill.svg 2x" src="https://d3ml3b6vywsj0z.cloudfront.net/website/v2/icons_v2/linkedin_icon_blue_fill.svg" width="22" height="22" decoding="async" data-nimg="1" loading="lazy" style="color:transparent">
</span>
```

I am trying to get the url of the above **img** tag in selenium with below code,

```
link_extract = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@alt ='linkedin icon']").click())
print(link_extract)
```

The above code opens the url in a new tab, whereas i need to get the URL of the LinkedIn img button.

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

you can use the get_attribute method to retrieve the src attribute.

```
linkedin_img = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@alt ='linkedin icon']"))
    
# Get the URL from the src attribute
linkedin_url = linkedin_img.get_attribute("src")
```

Comment: Hi @pensive, thanks for replying. I have tried a similar approach already. both my approach and ur code gives the url which is already in the srcset in img tag, which gives the LinkedIn icon not the actual URL of the site. which is this "https://d3ml3b6vywsj0z.cloudfront.net/website/v2/icons_v2/linkedin_icon_blue_fill.svg"

Comment: so you need to change your selector for what ever you want to get specific img url

Comment: what exactly you meant by change your selector ? i am totally new to this, just fixing some bugs in a code.. any help is much appreciated

Comment: i might not be able to help you without knowing what exact are you thinking to do!

Comment: There is a LinkedIn img icon in our website, there was a code which used to take the exact LinkedIn URL of the img, Now the UI team has updated some code because of which the we are getting a different set of tags for the same LinkedIn image (the <span> tag i had mentioned in question). Just need to get the actual company's LinkedIn URL from Python selenium code.

Comment: hmm but how may i get to know what was the changes your team have made and how are they correlated to the LinkedIn url